# How to add regular expression to my router.get()?

Tags: regex, node.js, express

Working good:

```
router.get('/:id([0-9]{3,8})', function(...)
```

Ain't working...:

```
router.get('/:id(/./)', function(...)
router.get('/:id/./', function(...)
router.get('/:id/(.)/', function(...)
```

Why? Actually I need RegExp, that mean 'numbers or symbols, 9 chars', but can't do it myyself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three code examples that don't work are not valid format for a route with a regular expression. The regular expression is put in parentheses and does not have leading and trailing slashes.

For details, refer to the documentation of the path-to-regexp module, which is what Express uses:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp